# Debug a numeric value in a date column SQL

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a couple of queries running in Google Sheets via Supermetrics.
These all have a column with the date ('2020-05-26') and a numeric column Cost ('3450')
Sometimes in rerunning these queries one of the rows does not show a date format, but a date formatted as number, e.g. '43976' for 2020-05-25. I am importing the sheets in Big Query, but when importing the date column as a date format, I get an error whenever there is one row formatted as a number.

I tried using an arrayformula in Google Sheets to overcome the formatting issue there, but that does not work since you cannot import a column with aan array formula in Google sheets.

I tried importing the column as a string, that works. Now however, I need to make sure all rows are recognised as a date. I used the following formula to change the string into a date, but again that one row formatted as '43976' will block the whole query.

How do I convert a string column, with both values formatted as a date "2020-05-25" and values formatted as a number '43976' to a date column? Thanks for your help!

Hereby a screenshot; however, the formatting is overwritten by the supermetrics query that is run daily, so just changing the formatting in the column here won't help (it will fix it for this day, but not going forward) - I've tried that already..

[image: demo]

Comment: Please share a demo sheet. Your question is about formatting thus a demo sheet with the formulas would be of great help in solving the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to share an attachment. There aren't any formula's however, since it's a sheet where a daily query via the supermetrics add-on provides the numbers. I added a screenshot, i hope that clarifies it! Thanks much!

Comment: *"formatting is overwritten by the supermetrics query that is run daily, so just changing the formatting in the column here won't help"*. If formulas are irrelevant, then you should probably get some support from supermetrics like [here](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000049396-i-need-to-change-the-date-formatting-in-my-results) or see if and how is the the particular cell different at its source. :/

Comment: share a copy of your sheet